# How to switch template in angular directive by the condition of `index` value

Tags: angularjs

I require to change the `template` according to the count of `index` getting from the `ng-repeat` how to achieve that?

in my case if `index` is 0, i want to change the `template'
here is my code :

```
"use strict";
angular.module("tcpApp")

    .directive('programName', function () {
        return {
            restrict    : 'AE',
            replace     : true,
            scope       : {
                            name:'@',
                            index:'@'
                        },
            template    : '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}</h2>',
            link        : function (scope, element, attr) {
                            scope.callMe = function () {
                                console.log($(element).prop('class'));
                            }
                        }
        }
    });
```

i tried like this but throws error:

```
    template    : scope.index ? '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}</h2>' : '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}arif</h2>',
```

error: `ReferenceError: scope is not defined`

**HTML**

```
<div class="progName">
                <div class="swiper"></div>

                <program-name name="{{appName.title}}" data-page="Home" index="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="appName in appNames"></program-name>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested but you should be able to do something like this one :

```
.directive('programName', function ( $compile ) {
        return {
            restrict    : 'AE',
            replace     : true,
            scope       : {
                            name:'@',
                            index:'@'
                        },

            link        : function (scope, element, attr) {
                            scope.callMe = function () {
                                console.log($(element).prop('class'));
                            }

                            var getTemplate = function( index ) {
                              return Number(index) ? '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}</h2>' : '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}arif</h2>';
                             }

                             element.html(getTemplate(scope.index));

                            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                        }
        }
    })
```

**EDIT**

Or even better solution could be:

```
.directive('programName', function ( ) {
            return {
                restrict    : 'AE',
                replace     : true,
                scope       : {
                                name:'@',
                                index:'@'
                            },

                template : function(tElement, tAttrs) {
                      return Number(tAttrs.index) ? '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}</h2>' : '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}arif</h2>';
                },  
                link        : function (scope, element, attr) {
                                scope.callMe = function () {
                                    console.log($(element).prop('class'));
                                }
                            }
            }
        })
```

Comment: console.log(Number(tAttrs.index)) - results as 'Nan'

Comment: @3gwebtrain do you have `index` attribute in your directive ?

Comment: In the scope i have.. what else? i have updated my `html` part to question can you have a look in that?

Comment: you'll need to `$parse` your attribute value first to get the evaluated `{{ $index }}` value, which is not possible inside of `template` function so I suggest you to go with my old answer if you are happy with that code.

Comment: Your first answer works, why your second solution not working for me? what i need to alter here? I am not think that the first solution so easy to understand.

Comment: 1. `scope` will not be available in template function 
2. The argument which you are referring as `scope` is actually `tElement` and the prove is first comment by you in Ismapro 's answer.
3. The second argument in template function is `tAttrs` (a list of attributes used with given directive) , but the bad luck is you can't access evaluated attribute value at that time
4. My suggestion again is to go with my first answer
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the scope in the code so that you can use it in your condition

```
template : function (scope){return scope.index ? '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}</h2>' :
                                   '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}arif</h2>'},
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OwU6099NuaPkRqP9QejQ?p=preview

Comment: console.log(scope) - gives the result as `[program-name, context: program-name]` there is no index, let me update my html in question

Comment: I forked it public , what do you mean by there is no index ?

Comment: Don't forget to define you appNames in in the controller i updated the plunk as example

Comment: Ismapro is using angular 1.4 in Pluker so there is scope in template function but may be 3gwebtrain is using older versions of angular where scope is not available in template function.

Comment: all using the second template which contains `arif' where is without `arif` template returned?

Comment: @Lekhnath, I use ` AngularJS v1.4.0` at present.

Comment: @Ismapro -  console.log(scope.index); gives `undefined' can you check?

Comment: 1. `scope` will not be available in template function 
2. The argument which you are referring as `scope` is actually `tElement` and the prove is first comment by 3gwebtrain.
3. The second argument in template function is `tAttrs` (a list of attributes used with given directive) , but the bad luck is you can't access evaluated attribute value at that time
4. My suggestion again is to go with my first answer
Thanks,

Comment: yes i agree actually I tought it was the scope but was not. tAttrs give the right value for the conditional contition.